# Map[Int, Option[Int]] returns Some(None)

Tags: scala

while programming some Scala I realized the following:

```
Map[Int, Option[Int]]().updated(3, None).get(3)
```

returns

```
Some(None)
```

instead of the expected

```
None
```

This seems very counterintuitive. Is this expected behavior or is this a bug.

I'm on Scala 2.13.8 by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very much expected behavior. `Option` is a "data structure" like any other, so there's no special handling of it from the compiler's side. If you associate a `None` with a key in that map, then there's an entry there and `Map` will report it.

If you want the behavior you expected, then either:

1. Don't store values as `Option`s, but instead use the plain `Int` type, or
2. `flatten` the result at the end: `get(3).flatten`.

A similar thing will happen if you put `Option`s inside `Option`s — there's no automagic flattening:

```
scala> Option(None)
val res0: Option[None.type] = Some(None)

scala> .flatten
val res1: Option[Nothing] = None
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is expected behavior as you can clearly see from the signature of `Map.get`:  `def get(key: K): Option[V]` .

In your case, `V` is `Option[Int]`, so the result of `get` is `Option[Option[Int]]`.

It is kinda unusual to have `Option` as value in a Map, in most cases, it is redundant, because you could just not have an entry in the map at all rather than storing `None`.

One use cases I can think of where it would be useful is implementing some kind of a cache: in that case, `None` would mean, the entry for the key does not exit, while missing key would indicate that it has not been checked.

Comment: Yes. The fact the get transforms V to Option[V] did escape me somehow.

Comment: @Cornelius if you don't want the transformation, you could use `.apply` instead of `.get`:  `map(3)` would return `None`. However, it is considered bad practice in most cases, because it would throw if the key is missing.